# rm: cannot lstat `cd1/Linux/nic/UBUNTU11_64/ââÃ¢\033\nwâ·.Î±Ão': Input/output error

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel6

am trying to delete folder in My rhel machine , but is giving error like

rm: cannot lstat `cd1/Linux/nic/UBUNTU11_64/ââÃ¢\033\nwâ·.Î±Ão': Input/output error

folder permissions are rwx to all

thanks
mahesh

Comment: That's...an interesting file path. Have you run `fsck` recently? Seems like a corrupted file.

Comment: i didt use fsck command but in that directory displaying all junk and corrupted files

Comment: What does SMART say? Do you have any bad sectors?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a corrupted folder and subfolders. I highly recommend running `fsck` on the drive and seeing if that either renames the files to something that you can delete or removes the entries entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If the filesystem is verified from fsck, you can use the "-i" flag on rm.

```
$cd /path/to/directory/ 
$ rm -i *
rm: cannot remove directory File-Path-2.08
rm: remove File-Path-2.08.tar? n
rm: remove Makefile? y 
<etc...>
```